# Translation of a simple sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

First I want to say that I'm just a beginner so my sentence may seem very easy to translate.

So I just imagined a simple situation. If I were to give, for example, a box of chocolates to a host family, I figured I could say something like

"I opened it to check if it wasn't melted".

What's a translation for that sentence?

What I find hard to translate is the "if it wasn't melted" part. Would it be something like "溶かされたら" ?

Comment: Did you also eat some to check that they tasted okay? I've just asked a related question which will hopefully help with yours: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83212/difference-between-embedded-question-and-noun-phrase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, the passive form is unnatural in the Japanese language. We usually use チョコレートが溶けていないか確認する.

If the passive form is used, I feel something like someone intentionally tried to melt it before.